# How to stop .+ at the first instance of a character and not the last with regular expressions in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace:

```
'''<font size="3"><font color="blue"> SUMMER/WINTER CONFIGURATION FILES</font></font>'''
```

With:

```
='''<font color="blue"> SUMMER/WINTER CONFIGURATION FILES</font>'''=
```

Now my existing code is:

```
$html =~ s/\n(.+)<font size=\".+?\">(.+)<\/font>(.+)\n/\n=$1$2$3=\n/gm
```

However this ends up with this as the result:

```
=''' SUMMER/WINTER CONFIGURATION FILES</font>'''=
```

Now I can see what is happening, it is matching `<font size ="..... all the way up to the end of the <font colour blue">` which is not what I want, I want it to stop at the first instance of **"** not the last, I thought that is what putting the ? mark there would do, however I've tried .+ .+? .* and .*? with the same result each time.

Anyone got any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't parse [X]HTML with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mark said, just use [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=html+treebuilder&mode=all) for this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $s = q{<font size="3"><font color="blue"> SUMMER/WINTER CONFIGURATION FILES</font></font>};

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$tree->parse( $s ); 
print $tree->find_by_attribute( color => 'blue' )->as_HTML;

# => <font color="blue"> SUMMER/WINTER CONFIGURATION FILES</font>
```

This works for your specific case, however:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $s = q{<font size="3"><font color="blue"> SUMMER/WINTER CONFIGURATION FILES</font></font>};

print $s =~ m{
                 < .+? >
                 (.+)?
                 </.+? >                
             }mx;

# => <font color="blue"> SUMMER/WINTER CONFIGURATION FILES</font>
```

Answer (score 8):

Write `.+?` **in all places** to make each match non-greedy.

```
$html =~ s/\n(.+?)<font size=\".+?\">(.+?)<\/font>(.+?)\n/\n=$1$2$3=\n/gm
                ^                ^      ^            ^
```

Also try to avoid using regular expressions to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser if possible.

Comment: Already tried this as per my comment and it didn't work. I haven't used HTML parsers before, any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

You could change `.+` to `[^"]+` (instead of "match anything", "match anything that isn't a `"`"...

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't match anything at all, here is what I used: $html =~ s/\n(.+?)<font size="[^"]+">(.+)<\/font>(.+?)\n/\n===$1$2$3===\n/m;

Comment: Hmm it worked on the string I posted in the example, but it fails to match at all on this example, ideas?:'''<font size="3"><span style="mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><font color="blue"> SUMMER/WINTER CONFIGURATION FILES</font></span></font>'''